# Secondary damage: Express.js sees no error page. Primary damage: ?newcomer's Mongoose mistake?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I found a similar question at [500 Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30182256/500-error-failed-to-lookup-view-index-in-views-directory), but I thought I had extensions covered.

In order to be able to work with HTML-like templates, I have, in my app.js:

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

In the views directory I have `error.html`, `error.jade`, and a zero byte `error` file. The `error.html` lacks interesting formatting but contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Error</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <%= message =>
  <%= error.status =>
  <%= error.stack =>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I try to access a page to create a user account (by adding an entry in Mongoose), I get an error on trying to save:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "/Users/jonathan/server/views"
    at EventEmitter.app.render (/Users/jonathan/server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:555:17)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/Users/jonathan/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:938:7)
    at module.exports (/Users/jonathan/server/app.js:106:7)
...
```

This is probably secondary damage about a failure to report an error page after something failed at my attempted insertion into the database.

I believe that the primary damage is with Mongoose; the code I believe to be relevant is:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema;
var user_details = new schema(
  {
  username: String,
  password: String
  },
  {
  collection: 'userInfo'
  });

passport.use(new local_strategy(function(username, password, done)
  {
  process.nextTick(function()
    {
    user_details.findOne(
      {
      'username': username,
      }, function(err, user)
      {
      if (err)
        {
        return done(err);
        }
      if (!user)
        {
        return done(null, false);
        }
      if (user.password !== password)
        {
        return done(null, false);
        }
      return done(null, user);
      });
    });
  }));
```

In my routes/index.js, the handler for POSTs to /newuser is:

```
router.post('/newuser', function(request, response, next)
  {
  var newuser = new user_details(
    {
    'username': request.params.username,
    'password': request.params.password
    });
  newuser.save();
  });
```

--UPDATE--

Per a request in a comment, here is my app.js file:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var express = require('express');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose/');
var path = require('path');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var passport = require('passport');
var local_strategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// app.use(app.router);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done)
  {
  done(null, user);
  });

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done)
  {
  done(null, user);
  });

var schema = mongoose.Schema;
var user_details = new schema(
  {
  username: String,
  password: String
  },
  {
  collection: 'userInfo'
  });

passport.use(new local_strategy(function(username, password, done)
  {
  process.nextTick(function()
    {
    user_details.findOne(
      {
      'username': username,
      }, function(err, user)
      {
      if (err)
        {
        return done(err);
        }
      if (!user)
        {
        return done(null, false);
        }
      if (user.password !== password)
        {
        return done(null, false);
        }
      return done(null, user);
      });
    });
  }));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

var server = app.listen(8000, function()
  {
  console.log('Server running.');
  });

module.exports = app;
```

--FURTHER UPDATE--

Now, after creating index.ejs, I am getting an error of:

```
Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%=".
   at /Users/jonathan/server/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:514:19
   at Array.forEach (native)
   at Object.Template.generateSource  (/Users/jonathan/server/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:501:15)
   at Object.Template.compile (/Users/jonathan/server/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:423:12)
   at Object.compile (/Users/jonathan/server/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:288:16)
   at handleCache (/Users/jonathan/server/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:147:16)
   at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/jonathan/server/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:350:14)
   at View.render (/Users/jonathan/server/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:93:8)
   at EventEmitter.app.render (/Users/jonathan/server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:566:10)
   at ServerResponse.res.render (/Users/jonathan/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:938:7)
   at module.exports (/Users/jonathan/server/app.js:106:11)
   at Layer.handle_error (/Users/jonathan/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:58:5)
   at trim_prefix (/Users/jonathan/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:300:13)
   at /Users/jonathan/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:7
   at Function.proto.process_params (/Users/jonathan/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
   at IncomingMessage.next (/Users/jonathan/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
```

The error page source is as quoted above.

What can I do to (ideally) address the primary damage?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you please add your app.js file as well? Also, why do you have three error files in your views dir instead of just one? Lastly, you should be using that "response" in your router.post to respond with new data or render a view to the user after the save action is done.

Comment: Why not take the error message at face value? Not finding a resource is not finding a resource.

Comment: @user2864740, I understand that a resource has not been found. I am trying to find out why it is not finding "error" when it has been told to look for "html" and there is a views/error.html.

Comment: Because it's *not* finding the view in "/Users/jonathan/server/views"?

Comment: @RahatMahbub, error.jade came with the project and hasn't been removed; error was to check if it was not looking for an extension.

Comment: @user2864740, from the shell: Inner Sanctum ~/server/views $ ls -l ~/server/views/index.html
-rw-r--r--  1 jonathan  staff  909 Jul  2 12:00 /Users/jonathan/server/views/index.html

Comment: How about 'error.html'?

Comment: Inner Sanctum ~/server/views $ ls -l ~/server/views/error.html
-rw-r--r--  1 jonathan  staff  232 Jul  2 11:59 /Users/jonathan/server/views/error.html

Comment: And if error.ejs (clone of error.html) is created? Basically there are two questions/problems here, neither is very well isolated. Once one is eliminated the other can focused on, probably with cleanup of: "secondary" and "primary".

Comment: I have posted a little added information (the error trace, which has me slightly confused; I don't know EJS very well but I would not expect ``<%= foo =>`` to cause a syntax error).

Comment: How can I specify EJS (or HTML) as as a template format? Inner Sanctum ~/server $ ack jade|grep -v node_modules
Inner Sanctum ~/server $

Answer (score 0):

```
 app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
 app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

These two lines are possibly conflicting each other. Remove the first line, remove all your .jade and .html files and keep only your .ejs files. Change your `error.html` to `error.ejs`. Everything should work as expected.

Comment: I've implemented that change, and now I am getting the ``<%=`` error traceback on all page views - not just new account creation.

Comment: That's because they should end with %> and not =>